# Linux process memory scheme

Tags: linux, unix, memory-management, process, linux-kernel

AFAIK there's a partition of a process memory that stores kernel related data and it's marked as read-only.

I can't find a factual explanation for why this happens, what is the purpose of this area and why should you include it in every process memory space ?

[image]

Comment: Do a `cat /proc/self/maps` and read more about its output.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the user-mode memory space, the kernel needs its own code section (RX), data section (R/RW), and stack frames for the threads (RW).

I would not say that it needs to be included in process memory space, but rather say that it's where the kernel always resides. Unlike the process memory space that gets replaced whenever there's a context switch between processes, the kernel space (>=0xC0000000 in 32bit and >=0xFFFFFFFF80000000 in 64bit), in its entirety, never gets replaced.

This is a necessary requirement since there's only one kernel on a system and it must remain at the same place in the memory (virtual) at all times for handling system calls, interrupts, and running various kernel tasks.